# Why does IMAP create a new folder in outlook

Tags: email, outlook, imap

I was setting up an email account in Outlook. Using IMAP as the transfer method it always makes a new INBOX. I only want one inbox, the original in the Personal Folders. The only way I could do it is with POP3. Why is this and is there a way to use the Inbox in the personal folders with IMAP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

POP3 is a retrieval protocol. It picks up the messages and delivers them to your local store.

IMAP4 is a direct access / sync protocol. It replicates the messages and the folder structure from the remote server to your local mailbox.